# How to import SFB file in runtime from local storage?

Tags: local, arcore, sceneform

I would like to render a file(andy.sfb) in ARcore. It is possible to get this file from `https://` and `file://`. Traditionally the file:// is allocated to files in the assets folder , which is packaged with the app. However, the aim is to download the 3D model, and then give the path (*URI*) from local device storage, this could be something like `/storage/emulated/0/Download/andy.sfb`. 
**SFB** stands for SceneForm Binary.

My challenge has been to render the model runtime from local device storage. 
The issue is presented here in [detail](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/367)

```java
  File file = new File("file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/andy.sfb");
            Callable callable = () -> {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            return inputStream;
        };
        FutureTask task = new FutureTask<>(callable);
        new Thread(task).start();

        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, callable)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Toast toast =
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        });
```

Comment: You can download .sfb file from server to local storage and load that .sfb file.

Comment: I am having the issue right now, I can successfully download to local storage but not able to retrieve(load) the file . https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/528

Answer (score 1):

You can download .sfb file from server to local storage and load that .sfb file.
To load object from local storage use below code:

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(path + fileName)))
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable -> {
                andyRenderable = renderable;
            })
            .exceptionally(
                    throwable -> {
                        Toast toast =
                              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return null;
                    });
```